# stop uninstallation of application in android

Tags: android

I an making security application, in which I have to do stop the application from uninstallation ,once it is install in device, have anyone do it before.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like a duplicate to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477206/stop-uninstallation-of-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if an app was uninstalled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680758/detect-if-an-app-was-uninstalled)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will not let the application to uninstall, unless the user explicitly un-checks the permission from the Admin settings of the device.

Use DeviceAdminReceiver class to get that functionality, extend your class say DeviceAdminSample from DeviceAdminReceiver. Also remember to add following in your manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".DeviceAdminSample" android:label="My App Admin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add this in xml folder of your res folder

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
    <force-lock />
</uses-policies>
```

Hope that helps. There might be other solution as well.