# Android - is there a way to tell how many times my app has been uninstalled?

Tags: android

Just trying to understand what can be measured.  Is there a way to measure the number of uninstalls?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680758/detect-if-an-app-was-uninstalled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a way to tell!!! It is in your android account management. They give a listing on total installs and total active installs!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think is any to remember the count for the number of times the app is uninstalled. Also i think you can know about the other app that are being uninstalled rather then your.

Answer (score 0):

No Actually..we don't have any metrics for them. There are no methods too in Android, which get called when the app is being uninstalled.

Comment: Android broadcast intent to all application except the one which is getting uninstalled.